# segmentation error before return statement in c

Tags: c, mpeg2-ts

I compiled and run the code successfully.but after that i am getting segmentation problem ,I checked the code again and again but i didn't got the reason for segmentation error,somebody please help me to fix this issue.

here is my code ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        unsigned long long int I_frame=0,P_frame=0,B_frame=0;
        printf("File name is :%s\n",argv[1]);
        int read=0,ts_header_size=0,adapt=-1,pld=-1,k=0;
        char buff[4],picture_buff[2];
        FILE *fp=NULL,*fp1=NULL,*fout=NULL;
        fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
                printf("failed to  open the file :%s\n",argv[1]);
                exit(0);
        }
        fp1=fopen(argv[2],"r");
        if(fp1==NULL)
        {
                printf("failed to open file :%s\n",argv[2]);
                exit(0);
        }
        printf("second file name is:%s\n",argv[2]);
        fout=fopen(argv[3],"w+");
        if(fout==NULL)
        {
                printf("failed to open file :%s\n",argv[3]);
                exit(0);
        }
        printf("output file name is :%s\n",argv[3]);
        read=fread(buff,1,4,fp);
        while(read)
        {
                ts_header_size=4;
                if((buff[0]==0x00)&&(buff[1]==0x00)&&(buff[2]==0x01)&&(buff[3]==0x00))//picture header checking if present count I,B,P frames
                {
                        fwrite(buff,1,4,fout);                             
                        fread(picture_buff,1,2,fp);
                        fwrite(picture_buff,1,2,fout);
                        k=(((picture_buff[1])&0x38)>>3);                          
                        if(k==1)
                                I_frame++;
                        if(k==2)
                                P_frame++;
                        if(k==3)
                                B_frame++;

                        read=fread(buff,1,188,fp);
                }

                fwrite(buff,1,1,fout);
                buff[0]=buff[1];
                buff[1]=buff[2];
                buff[2]=buff[3];
                read=fread(buff+3,1,1,fp);

        }
         /*printing the I,P,B frame count*/
        printf("no of I frames are :%lld\n",I_frame);
        printf("no of P frames are :%lld\n",P_frame);
        printf("no of B frames are :%lld\n",B_frame);
        printf("hi\n");
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Give us the input file details and segmentation fault error message. So that we can help you.

Comment: input files are MPEG2 Video files

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
 read=fread(buff,1,188,fp);
```

You are attempting to read `188` bytes into an array that is only `4` bytes.

Another problem is that you're throwing away the previous `return` value here:

```
 read=fread(buff+3,1,1,fp);
```

Comment: thanks for your help ,but what is the problem with fread(buff+3,1,1,fp);

Comment: You're storing the `fread`'s `return` value here: `read=fread(buff,1,188,fp);` but throwing it away here: `read=fread(buff+3,1,1,fp);`.